# Cannot write to new partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I just purchased a new 4 TB Seagate HDD. I went to the partition manager and changed the partition's format from NTFS to ext4. Ever since I did this, I cannot write to the drive. It also doesn't seem to be mounting properly. I attached a screenshot of the partition info.

Also, is it normal to have to change the directory permissions after creating a new partition?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you actually make an `ext4` filesystem on the partition after changing its type in the partition manager? And yes, you are supposed to manage file and directory ownership.

Comment: Where is the screen shot ?

Comment: Can you mount the new drive's `ext4` partition with the following command line in a terminal window? `sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt` where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, so for example `/dev/sdb5`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is normal that you have to change the permissions or the ownership after you create a partition. If you're on a multi-user system, you don't want everyone to be able to do with your storage medium whatever they please, unless you granted them the rights to do so. By default, only root is allowed to write to a partition.

To grant yourself permission to do so, open the partition in Nautilus. Then, right-click blank space and choose "Open in Terminal". In the terminal, execute this command:

```
sudo chown yourusername .
```

If you want to grant every user full access (might come in handy if you use the same drive on different computers), you can give everyone full rights via this command:

```
sudo chmod 777 .
```

To recursively grant write access to every directory inside a partition, run the command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing is to mark a partition as `ext4`, another is actually to format it, i.e. to create a filesystem (in your case, an `ext4` filesystem) on it. You can mount a partition only after a filesystem has been created on it. Some partition managers may perform the formatting, but it’s best to use them to create and mark partitions, and use other tools to format them.

Comment: Please suggest some tool that works well for you, and maybe also some tool that can show, if there is a good file system.